# How can I have fadein effect and animation at the same time using jQuery

Tags: jquery

i wanna make a menu with #menu id and get a 2 effect like fadein and move animation in the same time . i white this code but the first run fadein and seccound run animation .i want run tow effect simultaneously .

```
        <div id="Menu" style="right=0px;width=100px;height=200px;display=none;background=black;"></div>

    <script>
  $(document).ready( function (){
         $(function () {
                $("#menu").fadeIn("1000");
                $("#menu").animate({
                right: '50px'
                }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });

        });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Fade in is merely adjusting opacity. Use it like a CSS property

Comment: what happened? why did you suddenly decide to mark the other answer as "accepted"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following code

```
<div id="menu"></div>

<a href="#" id="animate">Animate</a>
```

```
#menu{
    height:20px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```
 $(function () {
     $("#animate").click(function(){
         $("#menu").fadeIn("1000",function(){
             $("#menu").animate( 
                 {
                 //opacity: 0.25,
                 left: '+=100px'

               }, 1000, function() {
                // Animation complete.
          });
         });
     });
});
```

Here is the demo link : http://jsfiddle.net/shadow2burn/z5LsY/

Comment: tanks dear S.Russell. but your code have my code problem ... you write your function in the after complete section . so first your div run fade in and the next move it .

Comment: IF you wanna do the opposite  then just insert the fadein function // Animation complete. comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS opacity and animate both properties at the same time

```
$("#menu").animate({opacity: 1, left: '+=100px'}, 2000);
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5LsY/1/)**